# Python - Format/Trim so it gives the right time?

Tags: python, time, format, scheduled-tasks, trim

So I have been playing around alittle bit with schedule and I found [Schedule github](https://github.com/dbader/schedule) which had schedule and was also really nice and easy to use. So what I have done so far is:

```
UserInput = input('To run Schedule script - Press y\nTo run directly - Press n\n')

if(UserInput == 'n'):
    main()
elif(UserInput == 'y'):
    TimeUser = input('What time to start script? Format - HH:MM ')
    schedule.every().day.at(TimeUser).do(main)
    wipe()
    print('Schedule starts at: ' + TimeUser + ' - Waiting for time...')

    while True:
         schedule.run_pending()
         time.sleep(1)
         if(schedule.idle_seconds() == '5'):
                 print('Program starts in...:\n' + str(schedule.idle_seconds()) + '\n')
```

However what Im getting for issue now is that my output turns out to be

Program starts in...:
30.08442

```
Program starts in...:
29.083967

Program starts in...:
28.083956

Program starts in...:
27.083923
```

and basically what I want to do is that  *if(schedule.idle_seconds()):* 5 secs. So when its 5 sec left it should start to print out. However the problem im getting is that it wont never reach 5 seconds because of the milliseconds I think. So I wonder if there is a way to maybe trim/cut/format it so it will start to print out when its 5 seconds left?

EDIT OUTPUTT:

```
--------------------------------------
Schedule starts at: 13:55 - Waiting for time...
--------------------------------------
Program starts in...:
4.748427

--------------------------------------
Wrong input - Try again
--------------------------------------
To run Schedule task - Press y
To run directly - Press n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, simplest way to trim float is: `int(variable)` but you can do that without trim. Try this:`if(schedule.idle_seconds() < 5.0):` instead of your condition. But it will be never-ending. If you want stop working of loop you must create additional condition.

For example:

```
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
    idle = schedule.idle_seconds()
    if(idle < 5.0) and (idle >= 0.0):
        print('Program starts in...:\n' + str(schedule.idle_seconds()) + '\n')
```

Comment: I think im getting the strangest bug ever. however when I try run this, It does say program starts in:.... but then tells me my input is wrong  after that.. Thats strange.. Im editing my thread to let you know the output

Comment: Well... Now it goes down to -0... 
```
Program starts in...:
2.733921

Program starts in...:
1.733449

Program starts in...:
0.732948

Program starts in...:
-0.267551

--------------------------------------
Wrong input - Try again
--------------------------------------
To run Schedule task - Press y
To run directly - Press n

```

Comment: I think instead of having `break` I could just use main(). Right?

Comment: It's probably caused by `break` in function. I fix bug, try this version,

Comment: Yay that worked! What I also did was `idle = int(round(schedule.idle_seconds()))` to round it so it gives me a full number instead of 4.412412

Comment: Ops. You are right though. Because of the time.sleep. Even if the program is complete. It will not end the program because of the sleep. Is there any solutions for that?

Answer (score 1):

The function returns a float, so comparing it to a string will never work.
However, you can probably do something along the lines of:

```
idle = int(round(schedule.idle_seconds()))
if idle == 5:
    print('Program starts in...:\n' + str(idle) + '\n')
```

If you want to be on the safe side, you can also floor instead of round:

```
idle = int(schedule.idle_seconds())
```

Comment: That did not work. So apprently when I tried to change to ```
                idle = int(round(schedule.idle_seconds()))
              
                while True:
                    print(idle)
                    schedule.run_pending()
                    time.sleep(1)
                    idletwo = int(schedule.idle_seconds())
                    if(idle == '5'):
                        print("Test: " + str(idle) + '\n')
```

It just was stuck at the same second. So if it was 36 sec left. It just printed out 36 36 36 36 36

Comment: `if idle == 5` does not equal `if idle == '5'`, but as your problem was solved anyhow, I guess we don't need to get into this in-depth. :)

Comment: I dont think so! Thank you aswell. Without your "Round" I wouldnt either got it!